# How to IgnoreAll spelling errors for a string VBA Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a list of several spelling errors. I´m looking a way to ignore all spelling errors for certain words from that list.

The code below it seems to work but only for text formatted with Style "Test"

```
ActiveDocument.Styles("Test").NoProofing = True
```

Is there a way via VBA to make something like this?

```
ActiveDocument.String("MyWord").SpellingErrors.IgnoreAll
```

Comment: There's `Document.ShowSpellingErrors` property which can be set to `False` if you don't want them to show up.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But if I do that will ignore all spelling errors in general not for specific text strings, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use Word's `Find/Replace` functionality to locate the word and apply the `NoProofing` formatting. The functionality allows searching for strings and through `Replace` applying formatting without affecting (deleting) the search term.

The following code snippet illustrates this. There are two variations:

1. Using Replace All to perform the action in one step
2. Searching and replacing one instance at a time

The first is faster, but in my tests the "squiggly red underline" denoting a spelling error is not removed from the document. The full Spell check ignores the terms, however.

The second (commented out), in my tests, does remove the error formatting, but will be slower in execution.

```
Sub FindToNoSpellCheck()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim findText As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    Set rng = ActiveDocument.content
    findText = "InsertY"
    Do
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = findText
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .Replacement.NoProofing = True
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
'        bFound = .Execute()
'        If bFound Then
'            rng.NoProofing = True
'            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
'        End If
    End With
    Loop While bFound
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent Cindy. Thanks so much for your help. It works very fine for me. As you said, the squiggly red underline is not removed, but I noticed that if I do right click over a word that red underline disappears. Is weird.

Comment: @GerCas I think the reason is a question of the visual interface vs. speed of application. To optimize the latter, the dynamic spell check and screen refresh aren't performed in the background, in the first case; the actions in the macro don't trigger them.